# Отловить нажатие на определенный маркер в Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

подскажите, как можно правильно отловить нажатие на определенный маркер на карте Google Maps и уже далее задать ему действие? Допустим, имеется три переменные Marker One; Two; Three;
Я сделала так, но работает только с третьего-четвертого клика по маркеру:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
...
One = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lat));
One.setTag(0);
// Set a listener for marker click.
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

}

public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

```
ExampleBottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new ExampleBottomSheetDialog();
bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "exampleBottomSheet");

// Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
if (marker.equals(One)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Balalaika: ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

return false;
```

}

Comment: Расшарьте код, сложно понять контекст где вы проверяете маркеры.

Comment: @SergeMarkov дополнила код

Answer (score 0):

Это всё ставиться при инициализации карты после getMapAsync()

```
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(
      (marker)-> {
          if(marker.getSnippet().equals(One.geSnippet())
           //DO WHAT YOU NEED

}
```

При создании маркера:

```
   gooleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                alpha(OPACITY_VALUE).
                anchor(0.5f, 0.5f).
                snippet(YOUR_IDENTIFIER_SNIPPET).
                position(YOUR_POSITION));
```

Answer (score 0):

Расширенная версия кода

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
...
One = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lat));
One.setTag(0);
// Set a listener for marker click.
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

}

public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

```
ExampleBottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new ExampleBottomSheetDialog();
bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "exampleBottomSheet");

// Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
if (marker.equals(One)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Balalaika: ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

return false;
```

}